# How do I show configuration with schema in the scheme popup menu?

Tags: xcode, configuration, xcode6

On my computer at the office, I can select the specific build configuration I want when selecting from the schema popup menu. At home, it doesn't show.

How do I get that to show?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was something like this:

[image: Scheme menu]

What I didn't realize is that this is a result of having multiple schemes selected from the Manage Schemes dialog. What I did to get this is added a couple of new Schemes and for each newly added scheme I edited it and selected the configuration I desired.

Now I don't have to option-click the run button to change the configuration, I simply select the device I want to run to from the scheme menu and then click the run button or select Archive from the Develop menu.

What's also nice is that the archives show the scheme name for the binaries stored there.

[image: Archive]